# Input 2nd file in R Shiny only if results from 1st Input file satisfies requirement

Tags: shiny, prediction

I am relatively new on using R Shiny, I am trying to build Shiny app for predictive modeling.
I have R code ready with me and have loaded them in R Shiny.

Please refer to below ui.r and server.r which I have prepared.

```
shinyUI(
  fluidPage(    
    titlePanel("Prediction"),
    sidebarLayout(      
      sidebarPanel(
        fileInput('file1', 'Choose Past CSV File',
                  accept=c('text/csv', 
                           'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', 
                           '.csv')),
        conditionalPanel(
          condition = "output.fileUploaded",
          fileInput('file2', 'Choose Future CSV File',
                    accept=c('text/csv', 
                             'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', 
                             '.csv')),
          downloadButton("downloadData", "Download Prediction")
        )
      ),
      mainPanel(
        tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                    tabPanel('Results', (DT::dataTableOutput('table'))),
      tabPanel("Model Summary", 
               verbatimTextOutput("summary"))
    )
      )
    )
  )
)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  # hide the output  
  output$fileUploaded <- reactive({
    return(!is.null(input$file1))
  })
  outputOptions(output, 'fileUploaded', suspendWhenHidden=FALSE)  
  data <- reactive({
    File <- input$file1
    if (is.null(File))
      return(NULL)
    complete <- read.csv(File$datapath,header=T,na.strings=c(""))
    File1 <- input$file2
    if (is.null(File1))
      return(NULL)
    raw.data  <- read.csv(File1$datapath,header=T,na.strings=c(""))
    #Change all variable to factor
    complete[] <- lapply(complete, factor)
    complete$Target <- recode(complete$Target," 'YES' = 1; 'Yes' = 1; 'NO' = 0 " )
    set.seed(33)
    splitIndex <- createDataPartition(complete$Target, p = .75, list = FALSE, times = 1)
    trainData <- complete[ splitIndex,]
    testData  <- complete[-splitIndex,]
    fitControl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", number = 4, repeats = 4)
    set.seed(33)
    gbmFit1 <- train(as.factor(Target) ~ ., data = trainData, method = "gbm", trControl = fitControl,verbose = FALSE)
    pred <- predict(gbmFit1, testData,type= "prob")[,2] 
    perf = prediction(pred, testData$Target)
    pred1 = performance(perf, "tpr","fpr")
    acc.perf <- performance(perf, "acc")
    ind = which.max( slot(acc.perf, "y.values")[[1]])
    acc = slot(acc.perf, "y.values")[[1]][ind]
    output$summary <- renderPrint({
      print(c(Accuracy=acc))
    })
    raw.data[] <- lapply(raw.data, factor)
    testpred <- predict(gbmFit1, raw.data,type= "prob")[,2] 
    final  = cbind(raw.data, testpred)
    final
  })
  output$table = DT::renderDataTable({
    final <- data()
    DT::datatable(
      data(), options = list(
        pageLength = 5)
    )
  })
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() { paste('SLA Prediction', '.csv', sep='') },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(data(),file)
    }
  ) 
  return(output)
})
```

Model is created using first Input file, my requirement is user should asked to upload 2nd input file (for which they want to predict results) only if model Accuracy which calculated using first input file stored in variable acc should be more than 0.9, I am not able to get solution for this, can anyone help me in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now the second file input depends on the variable `acc` and shows up only when it is bigger than 0.9. I additionally did some changes, mainly because your code didn't work on my laptop :). Instead of `return(NULL)` you can use the function `req` to ensure that the values are available.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinysky)
library(shinythemes)
library(caret)
library(gbm)
library(ROCR)
library(car)

ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    theme = shinytheme("united"), # added new theme from the package 'shinythemes'    
    titlePanel("Prediction"),
    sidebarLayout(      
      sidebarPanel(
        fileInput('file1', 'Choose Past CSV File',
                  accept=c('text/csv', 
                           'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', 
                           '.csv')),
        uiOutput("dynamic")
      ),
      mainPanel(
        # added busyIndicator 
        busyIndicator(text = "Calculation in progress..",
                      img = "shinysky/busyIndicator/ajaxloaderq.gif", wait = 500),

        tabsetPanel(type = "tabs",
                    tabPanel('Results', 
                      (DT::dataTableOutput('table'))),
                    tabPanel("Model Summary", 
                      verbatimTextOutput("summary")),
                    tabPanel("Predictions", 
                      DT::dataTableOutput('tablePred'))
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  # hide the output  
  output$fileUploaded <- reactive({
    return(!is.null(input$file1))
  })
  outputOptions(output, 'fileUploaded', suspendWhenHidden=FALSE)  


  data <- reactive({
    File <- input$file1
    req(File)
    complete <- read.csv(File$datapath,header=T,na.strings=c(""))
    complete
  })

  model <- reactive({ 

    complete <- lapply(data(), factor)
    complete$Target <- recode(data()$Target," 'YES' = 1; 'Yes' = 1; 'NO' = 0 " )
    set.seed(33)
    splitIndex <- createDataPartition(data()$Target, p = .75, list = FALSE, times = 1)
    trainData <- data()[ splitIndex,]
    testData  <- data()[-splitIndex,]
    fitControl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", number = 4, repeats = 4)
    set.seed(33)
    gbmFit1 <- train(as.factor(Target) ~ ., data = trainData, method = "gbm", trControl = fitControl,verbose = FALSE)
    pred <- predict(gbmFit1, testData, type= "prob")[,2] 
    perf = prediction(pred, testData$Target)
    pred1 = performance(perf, "tpr","fpr")
    acc.perf <- performance(perf, "acc")
    ind = which.max( slot(acc.perf, "y.values")[[1]])
    acc = slot(acc.perf, "y.values")[[1]][ind]
    retval <- list(model = gbmFit1, accuracy = acc)
    return(retval)
  })


  output$summary <- renderPrint({
    req(model())
    print(model())
  })


  output$dynamic <- renderUI({ 
    req(model())
    if (model()$accuracy >= 0.9)
      list(
        fileInput('file2', 'Choose Future CSV File',
                accept=c('text/csv', 
                         'text/comma-separated-values,text/plain', 
                         '.csv')),
        downloadButton("downloadData", "Download Prediction")
      )
  })


  data2 <- reactive({
    req(input$file2)
    File1 <- input$file2
    raw.data  <- read.csv(File1$datapath,header=T,na.strings=c(""))
    raw.data
  })

  preds <- reactive({ 
    raw.data <- data2()
    testpred <- predict(model()$model, raw.data,type= "prob")[,2]
    print(testpred)
    final  = cbind(raw.data, testpred)
    final
  })


  output$table = DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(data(), options = list(pageLength = 15))
  }) 

  output$tablePred = DT::renderDataTable({
    req(input$file2)
      DT::datatable(preds(), options = list(pageLength = 15))
  }) 

  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() { paste('SLA Prediction', '.csv', sep='') },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(preds(),file)
    }
  ) 
  return(output)
})


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I tried above code it is working fine. Just one question in Result tab in Shiny App, I need to display output which will be downloaded and this is available in final  = cbind(raw.data, testpred), but in Result tab I able to view data which I pass to create model, Can you please help me i this

Comment: Sure!   
If available - test data and predictions are now shown in new tabPanel. I also added a busyIndicator from the package `shinysky` and changed the theme with `shinythemes` package.

Comment: If you don't like the new tabPanel and want replace data in tabPanel "results", then you can remove it and replace output$table with:

`output$table = DT::renderDataTable({
  if (!is.null(input$file2)) { 
    DT::datatable(preds(), options = list(pageLength = 15))
  } else {
    DT::datatable(data(), options = list(pageLength = 15))
  }
}) `

Comment: This is awesome :) I able to replicate it. Thanks a lot. Actually now my main challenge is to replicate it for longer version of original codes as the code which I have shared while asking query have shortened , whether original codes have lots on manipulation on both datasets which are used to create model and predict results. When I update original shiny code using 1st structure you have shared it throw an error  "Error: argument "subset" is missing, with no default" on sidebar menu. I was not able to identify why I am getting this error. Could you please help me on this error

Comment: I would need more info in order to help you with that.

Comment: I able to replicate for longer version of original codes, I have added step by step in the Shiny part which you have shared. Again Thanks a lot for your help and guiding me.

Comment: I am very, very glad being able to help you :)